# Memory requirements to use TileMill efficently

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill

When trying to run TileMill with OSM Bright all I get is a "code 3" error, which apparently stands for "out of memory" error.

I'm trying to work on France, but I could restrict the work on one region at a time if it helped with memory.

The PostGIS db runs in a VirtualBox machine running Debian.

My PC is an Intel i5 with 4GB of RAM.

Should I:

- buy a new machine (I'd rather not)?
- rent something on AWS?
- run in a non-interactive way?

Or is there a commercial alternative to TileMill that's more efficient? Any other idea?

Comment: How much RAM and SWAP has your guest?

Comment: Rather than buying a new machine, can your current one accept additional memory?

Comment: Here's what I did: I dual-booted to Debian AMD64 (Wheezy) and put 8Gb of memory. Installing TileMill on Debian was a big pain but osm2psql was much much faster this way (8 hours instead of 35). It now seems to be working but it's quite slow (it could really use a progress bar!)

Comment: 8Gb memory: I meant I bought 8Gb and therefore now have 12Gb. It would appear the bottleneck is now the CPU (top indicates 99% for postgresql and at times over 200% for tilemill (??)).

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that 4GB of RAM should be sufficient.  It is possible that TileMill has a memory leak.  It certainly used to a while back, but I'd have assumed they'd have fixed that by now.  Since TileMill is based on node.js it maybe is suffering from a [limit on the heap size](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/) and you might be able to adjust that, but I'm no expert in that, so here are some alternative suggestions:

TileMill uses [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/faq/) for rendering, so you could use Mapnik directly in C++ or through the Python bindings and thereby cut out TileMill altogether.  You can then use Python's multiprocessing (not it's multithreading - that won't help because of the GIL) and hive off each tile rendering process into a subprocess which will close on completion and thereby help your speed and memory issues (hopefully).  Style definitions in TileMill and Mapnik are a little different in syntax so here's a link to the [OSM Standard Mapnik Style](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik).

Another alternative that should be very simple to implement could be to set up [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) with appropriate SLDs for your OSM data and then tell Geoserver to [seed its tile cache](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/layers.html).

Comment: Thank you for this answer; although Tilemill + postgresql osm db now work (on Debian with 8Gb, cf. above comment), using GeoServer sounds interesting. Is there a thorough tutorial on how to set this up? I found this http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/ which is interesting but doesn't explain the steps in detail...

Answer (score 1):

France is one of the larger OSM datasets that exists, thanks to France's community and a French building import.

If you're in the map design phase and extensively using Tilemill to try different map styles, using a much smaller extract of a small region of France would be much more efficient.

In any case, I doubt you would be able to export your project from tilemill with that limited setup. I would definitely change to a different server.

Comment: Your suggestion to restrict rendering to a small region of France makes a lot of sense (I'm not working on the whole country at the same time); and indeed there is an option in configure.py for osm-bright that lets one do just that (config["postgis"]["extent"]). However, the units are "spherical mercator meters" and I'm not sure how to translate from WGS84 to those, or determine them directly from a selection on the map...?

Comment: WGS84 to spherical mercator meters: there's a conversion script here that does exactly that (and more!) http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

Comment: Limiting to a region with onfig["postgis"]["extent"] changed everything! ;-)

Comment: Sorry... for GIS dummies... can you tell me what config["postgis"]["extent"] does? I am also having troubles with TileMill performance and like to increase it while designing my map...